# Which methods can I use to manually obfuscate my android app?

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, manual

I won't to make my android application almost impossible to reverse engineer. I have tried using ProGuard but since it doesn't encrypt my strings at all, it is not very useful for me.

I have seen this great obfuscator called Zelix KlassMaster, but I cannot afford it at this time.

Which methods can I use to manually obfuscate my application, or are there any classes that can help me like Mono.Cecil for .NET?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard). It's from the same people who made [ProGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/proguard). It costs money, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yet I am looking for free methods since I don't have enough money to pay for such tools at the moment.

Comment: Zelix KlassMaster tool free or cost?.is it possible obfuscate the string value also in klassmaster?